# How to treat brik dough?

Tags: dough

I have no experience at all with brik dough. This is a very thin and fragile dough that's mostly used for frying and baking.

Once the package is opened it should be used as the dough dries out really fast.

My question is how long after cooking does it stay crisp? Or can you re-crisp it if it becomes soggy?

Comment: Is brik dough the same as filo or pastry dough?

Comment: I guess it's thinner than filo. I'm not sure. I have wheat brik dough in the fridge.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filo_dough is apparently the same as brik dough http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brik...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, after experiencing, once cooked, the brik stays crisp for over a week.